# Function call should alter result if argument is missing (~overloading)

Tags: conditionals

What I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#2}}{}=0 %
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foo{1}{}

\end{document}
```

It results True if and only if \foo{someargument}{} is called.
What I need:
It should return True if and only if \foo{someargument} is called (so someone left the second parameter out). In the end I will replace True and False with two different function calls.

How can I do this?

Comment: TeX always grabs two arguments if you set up a macro with two parameters: are you trying to make an 'optional group' argument? That's not really recommended (it's not in line with how TeX works in general), but it is doable.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this: \entry{x}{y} registers glossary entry (x,y). \entry{x} prints the glossary entry. It has some advantages for me if I can implement it like this since I got used to using the command in the way it was used before (I decided to use the glossary package)

Comment: but if you declare mandatory arguments it is not possible to omit them `\entry{X}   \entry{Y}`  then `#2` of the first `\entry`  is not missing, it is the second `\entry`.

Comment: in your example, if you delete the `{}` then the second argument is not missing it is `\par` (from the blank line)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle this gives me a deeper understanding on why my attempt has failed. I personally thought it was a null "" error, but your explanation really helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trick TeX into doing something like this, but I strongly discourage from it. This isn't common (La)TeX syntax and in the long run it will likely cause more problems than it solves.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsgen}% for \new@ifnextchar

\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
   \new@ifnextchar\bgroup{\fooB{#1}}{\fooA{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\fooA}[1]{Only one: `#1'.}
\newcommand{\fooB}[2]{You've got two: `#1' and `#2'.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{1}

\foo{a}{b}

However: \foo{a}{}

\foo{a} {\bfseries This shouldn't do any harm.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is basically what the deprecated `xparse`  `g` parameter does.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know, but since I don't use `xparse` I do it the dumb way `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

If you declare a command with arguments, you can omit the `{}` but you can not omit the argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\detokenize{#2}}{\noexpand\par}=0 %
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foo{1}{2}

\foo34

\foo{1}

\end{document}
```

In the third call here, the second argument is not missing, it is the blank line, which is reported as `\par`.

If you omit the blank line the second argument is `\end`  then latex will typeset `document` and wait at the `*` prompt for you to type `\end{document}` to stop the run.

You could of course detect `\end` in your macro and return `\end` to the input in that case, but input such as `{\foo{1}}` will always give a low level error

```
! Argument of \foo has an extra }.
```

You could avoid the issue by not declaring the command has two arguments, as shown in the other answer, but this is taking you a long way from standard LaTeX syntax, where optional arguments are delimited by `[]` not `{}`.